# Excel - Search for specific text and delete the cell data, without affecting other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the below sample data set.

```
  Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
1   WB     WC      WD      WE
2   WB     xx      WD      WE
3   WB     WC      WD      WE
4   WB     xx      WD      WE
5   WB     WC      WD      WE
```

I need to search for `xx` in column B and delete cell A2 and cell B2 only. Not the whole row. Then shift row 3 data to row 2 for Col A and Col B.

Expected result

```
  Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
1   WB     WC      WD      WE
2   WB     WC      WD      WE
3                  WD      WE
4                  WD      WE
5                  WD      WE
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We can sort for specific columns but cannot filter, and do you provide the incorrect sample? Col B shoule be xx but not WC? Or you can use Advanced to copy the filtered result to new cells.

Comment: Edit the question,, you are deleting `XX` and both are in `Col B`. Since you want to delete the Cell not the Row. The easiest in Find `XX` and replace with Blank.

Comment: I can suggest you simple MACRO will exactly work in the way you are looking for.